# Firefox profiles pointing to different versions

Tags: firefox, user-profile

I am using Ubuntu 16 and Firefox 53. I need Firefox 45_ESR and 52.

Unpacked folder in `/opt/firefox45` and `/opt/firefox/52`.

Profiles created and stored in `~/.mozilla/firefox` but when I do `firefox -P nameOfProfile` the version that starts is the latest 53.0.

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

The version of Firefox is not given by the profile but rather by the executable itself.

You have to make sure the `firefox -P` command refers to the Firefox executable you are expecting. For example, to run a profile with Firefox 45, I would try to directly call the executable from `/opt/firefox45`:

```
/opt/firefox45/firefox -P
```

Assuming the executable lives in the root directory. A similar thing can be done for Firefox 52: just pick the executable from the related directory.